# Have and have got

Tags: british-english, have-got

native BrE speaker !

I am confused to use have and have got in the sentence. Do you (BrE speaker) use both "have got" and "have" in writing and speaking ?

ex.

A. I have a / I have to.

B. I don't have a / I don't have to.

c. Do I have a ? / do I have to ?

a. I have got a / I've got to.

b. I haven't got a / I haven't got to

c. Have I got a ? / have I got to ?

And, could I use " have got" In modal verb ?

ex.

a I could have (got) a  car /to go

b. I may have ( got) a car/to go

with to

a. Is it normal for her to have (got) to beat her child ?

b. My mum wants to have (got) a child.

with never

a. He never has (got) to pick / he never has (got) a red boat.

B. I am going to have (got) a child / to go

continous

a. I am having (got) to go / a car.

b. I am not having (got) to go / a car.

c. Am I having (got) to go / a car ?

Do you use have got in past form ?
A. I had a car / I had to go.
B. I didn't have a car / I didn't have to go.
C. Did I have a car ? / did I have to go ?

please, help me , I am really confused with these , and I'll wait for your help, thanks !

Comment: "Got" can be used with "have" in informal speech, but

Comment: (Sorry, took too long editing my original post) "Got" can be used with "have" in informal speech, but only on simple sentences like "I have got a dog." "He has got to go now". No-one would say "Is it normal for her to have got to beat her child?"

Comment: @KateBunting But I doubt, also, many would say  "Is it normal for her to have to beat her child". But they might say "Has she got to beat her child"?

Answer (score 0):

To me, (native BrE speaker), *got* is almost always required in the present: "I've got a car". Leaving it out ("I have a car") sounds formal, or American, to me.

But in any other tense than the present "I/you have got", it would tend to mean "obtained" not "posssess", so if I said "I had got a car" or "I will have got a car", I would be talking about having acquired one.  The same applies to non-finite uses, so "to have got" again would mean "to have obtained", not "to possess".

This applies too to questions and negatives. I say "I haven't got a car" and "Have you got a car?", but "I didn't have a car" and "Did you have a car?". The alternatives without 'got', "I haven't a car" and "Have you a car" sound formal to me; and "I don't have a car/Do you have a car?" sound American to me. (Having said that, these last forms are much more common in British English than they were fifty years ago, and I think I might even sometimes use them myself).